# Im receiving an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when trying to access my site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

im receiving these errors when trying to use my website. Any tips for troubleshooting these erros? Ive attached our s3 CORS policy.

Errors:
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (all.min.css, line 0)
[Error] Origin https://aecplatform.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 503
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://aecplatform.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 503 (signIn, line 0)
[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://api.aecplatform.com/user/signIn due to access control checks.

```
CORS Policy: 

[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Comment: Sounds like s3 assets load fine, so this isn't an S3 or AWS problem, right?  The API's CORS config is where you should be looking.

Comment: @erik258 you were right, then apis cars config was where the issue was located.